# Numbers written on a board

Tags: number-theory, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory, invariance

The numbers $1,2,...,n$ are written on a board ($n\in\mathbb N$). In each step we take any two numbers $a,b$, remove them, and write either $a-b$ or $a+b$ on the board. After $n-1$ steps there will be one number $t$ on the board. What numbers $t$ are achievable after $n-1$ steps?

It's clear that the parity of the sum of the numbers is invariant. So the parity of $t$ must match the parity of $1+\cdots+n=n(n+1)/2$. Can all the parity matching numbers be achieved? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Use induction on $n$, saving the number $n$ until last.

Comment: Is the assertion true? That all such $t\le Sum$ can be achieved?

Comment: Somebody smarter than I might want to check the tags. I don't see the connection to game theory, and I'm unsure regarding the others.

Answer (score 1):

It never hurts to gather some numeric data:

$$\begin{array}{c|l}
n&\text{possible results}\\ \hline
1&1\\
2&-1,1,3\\
3&-4,-2,0,2,4,6\\
4&-8,-6,-4,-2,0,2,4,6,8,10\\
5&-13,-11,-9,-7,-5,-3,-1,1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15
\end{array}$$

At this point it’s not hard to conjecture what the minimum and maximum possible outcomes are in terms of $n$, and that every integer of the same parity lying between those values is also a possible outcome. You can then prove the conjecture by induction on $n$. As **Michael** suggested in the comments, in the induction step consider first what happens when you leave the largest number for last. Then show that no other order of play can produce a result outside that range.